# custom UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I use below code for change image of each segment in segmentedControl but doesn't work

How to do it?

First way:

```
[seg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[seg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Second way:

```
[seg insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

[seg insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];

Comment: that should work. If you are using Interface Builder to make your seg object did you connect it well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems to be ok. If you have created the segment by using IB, check your the connections to the IBOutlet. Other possible case is that the images are broken. Try with another ones.

Answer (score 0):

The code works but you need to also set frame for your image. Otherwise the image simply occupies its space equal to its resolution on the screen.